# Excel won't let me select (or view) the source workbook with "Set varCellContent = Application.InputBox _"

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using the following code to choose a source worksheet by clicking any cell in the source workbook.

```
' User choose source sheet
Dim varCellContent As Worksheet
Set varCellContent = Application.InputBox _
    (prompt:=" " & vbNewLine & "Click any cell in source worksheet, then click OK", Type:=8).Parent
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Workbooks(varCellContent.Parent.Name).Worksheets("ap")
```

It has been working well for years but after making a few changes recently, Excel won't let me view or select the source workbook.  Funny thing is, the small changes I made were only *after* this section of the code, so it could well be unrelated to the code (Excel / Windows settings maybe??).

The source workbook is already open (a CSV file), but when I click it in the taskbar, it won't switch to it.  It seems like it could be related to both workbooks being open in the same instance of Excel, because it also won't let me dock (snap) both each workbook left and right seperately.  If I dock one to the left, then I try and dock the other to the right, but they both go together.  I am sure I have not noticed this behaviour before.

If I open another instance of Excel and then open the CSV file in that, I can dock seperately, and I can select the cell in the CSV file, but it is not reconised in the input box. (The cell reference does not show up when I click the cell).

Have done plenty of googling but can't work what the heck has happened!???

Comment: Added to code in original post above.  I don't think it is to do with code though, as I have gone back to the original workbook and that behaves in the same manner now.

Comment: So, if I understand your problem correctly, after running your code, the CSV file won't appear when you click on it from the taskbar. Have you tried `Workbooks(varCellContent.Parent.Name).Activate` instead?

Comment: OK, just tested this on another PC and it works fine (as it always did).  I tested both the original version and my updated copy that was not working on other PC.  So I guess that confirms it is not the code, as I expected.  I can also dock/snap the 2 workbooks separately left and right on this PC.  What has happened on the other PC that has changed this???  It must be an Excel issue, as I can dock 2 Chrome windows OK.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing your Excel version and how the 2 workbooks were opened. Were they opened manually by double-clicking the file or via VBA? Please edit your question to add those details.

Comment: UPDATE - I didn't realise this PC was running such an old version of Excel - 2007 SP3.  I installed the latest Office 356 version and it works again now.  It had been working fine previously so no idea what happened to the existing Excel install to change things!